# Why do we see an inverted image in a spoon when kept far from our face with concave side towards our face?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

We see a virtual inverted image whereas in case of concave mirror we can see a virtual image which is erect.

Answer (score 2):

*We see an inverted image in a spoon when kept far from our face with concave side towards our face.* It is because our face is outside the focal legth of the conave side of the spoon.

[image]

*We see a virtual inverted image whereas in case of concave mirror we can see a virtual image which is erect*. This is because when the object is between pole and focus the we get erect enlarged image.

I tried to get a virtual image with a spoon, but I couldn't get even after bringing it too close to my face, this is probably because the focal length of the spoon was too small.

@HarnoorSingh Yes the virtual image of the nail is formed when close to the mirror it is because the nail is between the pole and the focus of the font side (concave) of the spoon, resulting in the formation of virtual image on the spoon. This situation is depicted by the second diagram.

Comment: But that is real image and we see an image inside a mirror. So please consider my point. And about virtual image, you can see a virtual image by bringing your nail in front of the spoon, bringing it near our nail.

Comment: @HarnoorSingh Hope its clear :)